# How to use ZK4500 Fingerprint Scanner SDK in C# Project

Tags: c#, c++, sdk, fingerprint, biometrics

I am developing a project in C#, for which I want to login/authenticate a user using their fingerprint.

I bought a ZK4500 Fingerprint scanner and got its SDK from http://www.zkteco.com/product/ZK4500_238.html. The SDK is in C++.

So How can I integrate this SDK with my C# project to perform the desired functionality?

Comment: Please don't make keywords bold. You should use tags to emphasize keywords.

Comment: This article is exactly what you are looking for : https://www.debuggershub.com/c-zkteco-fingerprint-scanner-implementation-zk4500-slk20m-slk20r-zk9500/

Answer (score 6):

You need to add reference to ZKFPEngXControl that will appear under COM Type Libraries. After that you can use the ZKFPEngX Class to do whatever you require.

```
using ZKFPEngXControl;
```

and then

```
ZKFPEngX fp = new ZKFPEngX();
fp.SensorIndex = 0;
fp.InitEngine(); // Do validation as well as it returns an integer (0 for success, else error code 1-3)
//subscribe to event for getting when user places his/her finger
fp.OnImageReceived += new IZKFPEngXEvents_OnImageReceivedEventHandler(fp_OnImageReceived);
```

You can write your own method fp_OnImageReceived to handle the event. for example you can write this in that method;

```
object imgdata = new object();
bool b = fp.GetFingerImage(ref imgdata);
```

Where imgdata is an array of bytes.You can also use other methods in ZKFPEngX, to achieve your goals. Remember to close the engine when form closes.

```
fp.EndEngine();
```

Comment: I am really delighted to have your consideration, your answer is helping and the things seems to me on the right track. But would you please help me more to register user using this device and then authorize user fingerprint against registered fingerprints.

Comment: There must be a support document along with the SDK. Read it carefully to know what all functions and methods you can use. If you are not able to locate the pdf documentation file, then you can ask for it.

Comment: Yes it has the documentation file, but tis not helpful for me. Now I want to get image as string and store it to database like `zkfpeng.GetTemplateAsStringEx("10")` but it returns `null`, and after that I will compare both templates, the one from database with the one got from the biometric device on the spot, for authentication like `(zkfpEng.VerFingerFromStr(ref bTemp, sTemp, false, ref RegChanged)`. Now I am completely doodling in dark, So please guide me if it is feasible for you. **Thanks**.

Comment: as far as I know to be able to match two fingerprints you need third party SDK something like the one in the link below , the SDK of zk4500 can't help with this, unless you are willing to develop you own matching software 

the link : http://www.neurotechnology.com/free-fingerprint-verification-sdk.html

Answer (score 2):

You can store a fingerprint under `OnEnroll(bool ActionResult, object ATemplate)` Event.This event will be called when `BeginEnroll()` has been executed.

```
//Add an event handler on OnEnroll Event
ZKFPEngX x = new ZKFPEngX();
x.OnEnroll += X_OnEnroll; 


private void X_OnEnroll(bool ActionResult, object ATemplate)
{
    if (ActionResult)
    {
        if (x.LastQuality >= 80) //to ensure the fingerprint quality
        {
            string regTemplate = x.GetTemplateAsStringEx("9");
            File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\\fingerprint.txt", regTemplate);
        }
        else
        {
            //Quality is too low
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Register Failed
    }
}
```

You can try to verify the fingerprints under `OnCapture(bool ActionResult, object ATemplate)`event. This event will be called when a finger is put on the scanner.

Add an event handler on OnCapture Event:

```
x.OnCapture += X_OnCapture;
```

Verify the fingerprints when the event has been called (a finger is put on the scanner):

```
private void X_OnCapture(bool ActionResult, object ATemplate)
{
    if (ActionResult) //if fingerprint is captured successfully
    {
        bool ARegFeatureChanged = true;
        string regTemplate = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\\fingerprint.txt");
        string verTemplate = x.GetTemplateAsString();
        bool result = x.VerFingerFromStr(regTemplate , verTemplate, false, ARegFeatureChanged);
        if (result)
        {
            //matched
        }
        else
        {
            //not matched
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        //failed to capture a valid fingerprint
    }
}
```