# C# compatible Finger print reader and receipt generator

Tags: c#, printing, biometrics

I am planning to create School Management System in C# and I'm gonna provide these features:

- Biometric attendance system
- Fee Slip Printing

I did some search and found these 2 products (fits my needs, I think):

- [Finger Print Reader - ZK4500](https://www.zkteco.com/product/ZK4500_238.html)
- [Thermal Receipt Printer - XP200](https://www.digicartz.com/XP200-80MM-Thermal-Receipt-printer) (not official link)

I was about to order these products but I read on a website, **Make Sure the Device is compatible with Programming language** (in my case C#). I try to find the answer on Google but no luck! :(

I am totally hopeless and helpless but still happy :) because Stack Over Flow community is always here to help and give the right direction.

So, Here are my **questions**:

- Does these devices are configurable with C#? (if possible, please share any helpful resource)
- Is it better choice to use receipt printer instead of regular printer?
- Is there any better alternative available for fingerprint reader and receipt generator?

**PS:** I wanted to keep the printer and fingerprint reader cost as low as possible so customer can afford it easily.

Comment: https://programadorescs.blogspot.co.il/2016/11/fingerprint-sensor-zk4500-en-c-2015.html

Comment: thanks for the resource but it doesn't shows any guide or source code etc.

Comment: If you going to buy the product you need to connect the manufacture and ask them about the C# SDK and

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the ZK4500, but I can guarantee you that the Digital Persona U.are.U series can be used with C#. The SDK can be purchased as part of a package or standalone. I don't know how many devices you need, but I can tell you that I've had fairly good experience with the U.are.U 4500. The scanners are $99 each, SDK not included.

It also comes with examples for implementation with C#. You can choose to let the SDK handle everything for you, which means capturing a print, finding minutiae points, and creating a biometric template for you, or you can capture the raw image and do your own processing. The examples also show how to store it in your database.

Another option if you are set on a particular scanner is the neurotechnology fingerprint SDK. It includes drivers for many scanners and I can verify that it works well with C#.

Yet another option is the Griaule Biometrics SDK. This SDK also supports C# and is easy to use. It does not include drivers and only officially supports 6 scanners. Additionally, it may be a bit more difficult to get these days because Griaule recently changed their website and ended support for the older SDK. They seem to offer new SDKs, but I haven't used their newer products.

Regarding receipt printers...can't help you there.

Comment: thanks for your answer but that device is going to be expensive. :(

Comment: Well, in that case, I hope those SDK's will at least help.  The Neurotechnology SDK supports about 34 scanners. The list is [here](http://www.neurotechnology.com/free-fingerprint-verification-sdk-supported-scanners.html). Also, there was similar question on [using ZK4500 SDK in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876583/how-to-use-zk4500-fingerprint-scanner-sdk-in-c-sharp-project). As long as you have the C++ SDK, you can use it in C#.