# How to enroll and verify the fingerprint scanner? (ZKteco for Thesis)

Tags: mysql, vb.net

We have bought a ZKteco fingerprint scanner. The SDK is VC. We did not understand the sample program that was given.

How to enroll and verify all fingerprints with this scanner? Where do we start?

Comment: See if this can help . https://stackoverflow.com/a/43042582/1255274

Comment: thank khan. any other link for vb.net 2015?

Comment: Also.... Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). SO is not **a free Coding service. *We try to fix your code, we do not write your code***.

Comment: You can easily convert the c# code to vb.net using any converter... OR manually.

Comment: ok. i will try the code. thanks